# Chromedriver issues

Tags: npm, selenium-chromedriver

Running `npm update` up until Tuesday caused no issues but yesterday I received the following:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! chromedriver@2.43.4 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the chromedriver@2.43.4 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.
```

This in on my local machine but also occurs on a VSTS Pipeline. I've tried changing the Chromedriver to an older build...same issue. Tried on two machines...Win7PC and OSX...same result.

Anyone else getting this?
David